# domain in many2one field not restricting choices

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

**Stripped down code**:

```
class fnx_fs_folder(osv.Model):
    _name = 'fnx.fs.folder'
    _columns = {
        'folder_type': fields.selection(
            [('virtual', 'Virtual'), ('shared', 'Shared')],
            'Folder Type',
            ),
         {

class fnx_fs_file(osv.Model):
    _name = 'fnx.fs.file'
    _columns = {
        'folder_id': fields.many2one(
            'fnx.fs.folder',
            'Folder',
            help='Folder to present document in.',
            required=True,
            ondelete='restrict',
            domain="[('folder_type','=','virtual')]",
            ),
```

**Problem**:  Even though the `folder_id` field has a `domain` attached to it, the form view is still showing all folders, not just the ones that are `virtual`.

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause**:

In the `xml` file I had this:

```
<field name="folder_id" widget="selection" ... />
```

**Solution**:

Either remove the `widget` portion, change the widget to `many2one`, or, as [sjpatel notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25236097/208880), put the `domain` directly in the `xml` file.

*Note*:  Unfortunately, this shows that adding a `domain` in the `.py` file is not enforced, and cannot be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the domain in xml field directly , and it will work even with widget selection.